# int variable is not able to store large values

Tags: c++, integer, literals

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 999999999999999999;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << 999999999999999999 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of above program is `-1486618625` and  `999999999999999999`.

In both the `cout` we are giving the same number, so why are the outputs different?

Also are `long long int a=999999999999999` same as `int a=9999999999999999ll`?

Comment: are you sure it also does with long long int? 
The number 999999999999999 requires 64 bits, so it wint overflow the capacity of long long (on windows for instance), as it did with *int* in your example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign integer literal `999999999999999999` to `int a`, it may be truncated if the `int` type is not capable of representing that number.  The maximum value that can be stored in an `int` is `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` and depends on the platform you are compiling for (but must be at least 32767).  Your compiler should warn you about such a truncating assignment:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra    32689548.cpp   -o 32689548
32689548.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
32689548.cpp:5:13: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
     int a = 999999999999999999;
             ^
```

To answer your question, "[is] `long long int a=999999999999999` the same as `int a=9999999999999999ll`" - why not test it for yourself?  Like this, perhaps:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    long long int a = 999999999999999999;
    int b = 999999999999999999ll;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << (a==b) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```bash
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra    32689548.cpp   -o 32689548
32689548.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
32689548.cpp:6:13: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
     int b = 999999999999999999ll;
             ^
```

```bash
$ ./32689548
999999999999999999
-1486618625
0
```

Here we see that assigning a `long long` to `int b` causes the same truncation (as GCC warns us it will).   However, if we change `int b` to `auto b`, then we get no warnings and a true comparison:

```
999999999999999999
999999999999999999
1
```

For information, I built and ran the above on a system that has

```
std::numeric_limits<int>::max() = 2147483647
std::numeric_limits<long long int>::max() = 9223372036854775807
```

Comment: Then what is the use of ll suffix.Is it not used to specify that the integer is long long and then assign that much space for that integer value.

Comment: @Junior - yes, `ll` indicates that a literal is `long long` - but if you then assign it to `int` you'll get truncation.  Just the same as if you write `long long int a = 999999999999999999ll; int b = a`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you are assigning the value to an int, this is too large for an integer where max value is 2147483647, check this link for more info [C++ Data Types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm)

in the second case, cout will print whatever value you gave.

Answer (score 0):

assigning the constant number 999999999999999999 into an int variable (a) results in truncation and changes the value. However, if you declare it as **long long a**, there will be no truncation and it displays correctly on any platform that has 64 bits for a **long long** (i.e. Windows VC++).

Comment: _"results in truncation"_. No it does not, it results in overflow. Completely different behaviour.

Comment: @AndyBrown Here is the warning message from VC++: *...\consoleapplication1.cpp(10): warning C4305: 'initializing' : **truncation** from '__int64' to 'int'*

Comment: As a stalker, I think this answer doesn't deserve a down-vote.

Comment: @javaLover hey! :) as you see, we need to be very careful in choosing the words, the C++ society has a very strict and "templated" vocabulary :P

Answer (score 0):

Variable a is defined as signed integer data type - 4 bytes, and the range value of signed integer is [-2^31, 2^31]. For easy-understanding, value of data type is stored as round circle, so that the minimum value stands next by maximum value [..,max-1, max, min, min+1...]. It means the value of (maximum value + 1) is minimum value. 
When you do an assignment as `int a=999999999999999`, because this value is over range value of signed interger data type, a valid value in integer's range value is assigned to the variable a.

Line statement `cout<<a<<std::endl;` in essence is overloading of std operator `basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(int n)` - print out a signed integer value.

Line statement `cout<<999999999999999999;` is overloading `basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(long n)`, long data type is 8-bytes data type, value range contains the printed value '99..99', so value '99..99' is printed with no doubt.

Try define var a as long data type `long a = 999999999999999999`, then printing out will be successful.

Comment: `long` might not fix the problem, the standard only requires "at least" 32 bits. See the [integer properties table on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Comment: In fact, it should be `long long` or `long long int`. I tried compiling on x64 computer, sometimes long is defined as 64-bits data-type. [64 bits computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing)

Answer (score -2):

In the first you are declaring a as a variable of `int` type. The maximum value of `int` type is 2147483647 so whatever the value above it will be converted. So your long value was converted and stored and thats what was printed. But when you directly give it without any values, it can be any data type. Here the data type is `long long int`(64 bit int). So if your compiler, OS and hardware support 64 bit ints, then it will be printed. The first one also will be printed correctly if you declare it as `long long int`. The maximum value of `long long int` is **92233703685477807** which is almost enough to store **20!** (factorial of 20).

Comment: Then what's the use of long int?

Comment: There's a [good table on this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) that shows what the language standard says about integer types. As far as `long int` goes, it depends on the compiler and build options. It's at least 32-bits and might be 64-bits.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I changed the value. I was taught to use the Turbo C++ compiler only. I thought that same values apply for all compilers.

Comment: I kind of assumed you were talking about Turbo C++, it seems to be common in some education systems. It's unfortunate because DOS and Win16 are very old and not seen that much outside that environment. Note: I'm not one of your downvoters, glad you learned something new.

Comment: Yeah. Turbo C++ is what was thought in our education system. But GCC and G++ is what I use. Anyway thanks for your info.